# WordPress: How to show a metabox on any admin page?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

I already know how to register metaboxes for Posts, Page, and Custom Post Types, but I would like to register a metabox to be shown on my custom admin page, which is not a post.

My plugin has an "[Options Page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Options_Pages)" in the WordPress Admin – I would like to show metaboxes on this very page.

Is this possible? If yes, how can this be acheived?

I saw in the [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) documentation that one of the possible values for the `$post_type` parameter is `dashboard`, however this is not documented anywhere. I guess it would show the metabox on the WordPress Dashboard (the main admin screen when logging-in), but this is not what I need or want.

**Edit:**

*This question is about OptionTree Metaboxes, which uses the standard WordPress Metaboxes. Perhaps there is a better way to accomplish this by using OptionTree differently, or by modifying OptionTree? Please see this related question:* [How to have more than one "Theme Options" page with OptionTree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18414823/wordpress-optiontree-how-to-register-a-plugin-options-page-rather-than-a)

Comment: Check [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57092/12615).

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for the link! But using this method I'm not sure how would I save the metabox settings nor to what post ID it will be attached? How could I recover the "post meta" without an ID using `get_post_meta()`? Thanks!

Comment: @usernotfound check my answer below, and let me know about it

Comment: @JothiKannan thank you for your answer, for the past 24 hours I tried to make it work using the code linked, without success. Again your demo plugin (which is quit old and use deprecated methods) succeed at showing visual meta boxes which is nothing more than some DIVs with appropriate JS enqueuing, but when you actually need to have a real meta-box that do something and make use of the first parameter in the callback func (which is the current **post ID**) then the callback fails. Adding a die('enters here'); in the callback shows it's never called... I have WP_DEBUG ON and no error.

Answer (score 2):

if my understanding is right you can do it by following

Here is a [Demo plugin](https://gist.github.com/bueltge/757903) that can help you get it working.

> This WordPress Plugin demonstrates how you can build your own plugin
>   pages using the WordPress provided draggable metaboxes, requires
>   WordPress 2.7 version, supports WordPress 2.8 changed boxing layout
>   engine

Comment: @ Jothi Kannan thank you for the your answer. I did exactly what this demo plugin does, which is add_meta_box() and do_meta_boxes(), but it did not work. For some reason, calling do_meta_boxes() will never work, and I believe that it is because it's missing a **post ID**! Of course it does, if you check the WordPress Documentation you'll see that the callback function for add_meta_box() receives the post ID in the first parameter. I don't understand what would be passed on a "plugin page" that doesn't have any post ID... I believe that's the main issue.

Comment: Instead of `post_ID` you should pass `$this->pagehook`,it should work in the admin pages

Comment: Look into plugin file at line 60

Comment: @ Jothi Kannan sorry I wasn't clear, I was talking about the callback function specified in the 3rd parameter of add_meta_box(). WordPress usually passes to this function the post ID. In this case it doesn't work.

Comment: yes `add_meta_box('howto-metaboxes-sidebox-1', 'Sidebox 1 Title', array(&$this, 'on_sidebox_1_content'), $this->pagehook, 'side', 'core');` you must use `$this->pagehook` and you can create it on by line 60

Comment: ?? In the example you give, the 3rd parameter is `array(&$this, 'on_sidebox_1_content')` and it would make absolutely no sense to set it as `$this->pagehook`...

Comment: From codex `add_meta_box( $id, $title, $callback, $post_type, context, $priority, $callback_args );` , here 3rd argument is Post_ID ?but i think 4th one, so instead of $post we must use `$this->pagehook` we have created for certain page

Comment: Please re-read all my previous comments. And please re-read the Codex for [add_meta_box()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box). The 3rd parameter, as I said, is the callback functions that WordPress calls when the meta-box is rendered. When calling this callback function, WordPress passes the current `$post` object. Please refer to [Callback_args](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box#Callback_args) - However on a custom plugin page there is no `$post` object. Thank you fro trying to help anyway ;)

Comment: yes there is a callback function like `on_sidebox_1_content`to render the HTML content, in your 1st comment you said that `I don't understand what would be passed on a "plugin page" that doesn't have any post ID... I believe that's the main issue` so only i had illustrate the `$this->pagehook` instead of `post_ID`

Comment: "_yes there is a callback function like on_sidebox_1_content_" – Of course there is, and this one works well as it doesn't need any `$post` object to work. However it doesn't work for any meta-box relying on it for the purpose of setting [post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) data... In this case I'm trying to use "[OptionTree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) Metaboxes" which fails to render the meta-box :(

Comment: @ Jothi I gave you the bounty for the effort ;) It didn't solve my problem but I guess it's a viable solution for other case scenarios. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Never tried but just an idea.
In your plugins options page url pass another parameter say post-type and provide any new post type name. Then use this parameter value in add_meta_box() function $post_type = $_GET['post_type'].