# How to have more than one "Theme Options" page with OptionTree?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

[OptionTree](http://wordpress.org/plugins/option-tree/) ([GitHub](https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree)) allows to create a "**Theme Options**" page for themes very simply.

How could I extend OptionTree in order to create a "***Plugin* Options**" page for my plugin?

Thank you!

Comment: Another possible solution, use [Admin Page Class](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/7501/12615), from one of [wordpress.se] moderators.

Comment: @brasofilo Thank you for your input. Actually I'm not looking for another framework at all. OptionTree is very powerful since version 2.0, which was released _after_ the author of the answer you linked to dropped it. (Beside lot of my work is based on OptionTree, I use many of its available filters/hooks to customize its behavior, plus I'm very familiar with it so I really wouldn't drop this actively maintained framework).

Comment: Well, if your solution is relatively solid and works ok, then it's a good solution. Advanced Custom Fields works on a CPT basis and I use its *Options* add-on to create this kind of site-wide options. Anyway, asking for *"the best"* is normally considered opinion based and off-topic. And also, what does OptionTree author has to say about this?

Comment: _"what does OptionTree author has to say about this?"_ – He said, I quote: _"you need to create new option pages with different ID's it's not documented but can be done."_ See https://github.com/valendesigns/option-tree/issues/156

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. The following code will create a page under the settings page called **Test Page**. This is how OptionTree creates its own pages.

```
/**
 * Hook to register admin pages 
 */
add_action( 'init', 'register_options_pages' );

/**
 * Registers all the required admin pages.
 */
function register_options_pages() {

  // Only execute in admin & if OT is installed
  if ( is_admin() && function_exists( 'ot_register_settings' ) ) {

    // Register the pages
    ot_register_settings( 
      array(
        array( 
          'id'              => 'custom_options',
          'pages'           => array(
            array(
              'id'              => 'test_page',
              'parent_slug'     => 'options-general.php',
              'page_title'      => 'Test Page',
              'menu_title'      => 'Test Page',
              'capability'      => 'edit_theme_options',
              'menu_slug'       => 'test-page',
              'icon_url'        => null,
              'position'        => null,
              'updated_message' => 'Test Page updated.',
              'reset_message'   => 'Test Page reset.',
              'button_text'     => 'Save Changes',
              'show_buttons'    => true,
              'screen_icon'     => 'options-general',
              'contextual_help' => null,
              'sections'        => array(
                array(
                  'id'          => 'test_section',
                  'title'       => __( 'Test Section', 'motif-core' )
                )
              ),
              'settings'        => array(
                array(
                  'id'          => 'test_section_input',
                  'label'       => 'Test Input',
                  'desc'        => 'Pretty freaking awesome!',
                  'std'         => '',
                  'type'        => 'text',
                  'section'     => 'test_section',
                  'class'       => ''
                )
              )
            )
          )
        )
      )
    );

  }

}
```

Comment: In case someone wonders, here is how to retrieve the stored data: `$my_plugin_options = get_option('custom_options');`